# The newly generated .css by SASS now doesn't have comments to tell which file the css is from, what might be causing it?

Tags: sass

The old generated .css file has

```
 /* line 27, ../../../app/stylesheets/partials/products/_summary_pane.sass */
```

which tells where the css (or sass) is originally from.  (example: the above say it is from _summary_pane.sass)

and now all of a sudden, these lines are all gone.  What might be the cause for it?

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the following option:

```
Sass::Plugin.options[:debug_info] = true
```

[Docs here](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#options).

This also may be of interest to you:

http://nex-3.com/posts/92-firesass-bridges-the-gap-between-sass-and-firebug

Comment: Actually, `:line_numbers` is the option for line comments in source, `:debug_info` is a lot more output.